# c# sending file between 2 subnets via ip address

Tags: c#, winforms, networking

I am trying to send a file over the internet by using the ip address of the receiver. I managed to successfully send the file between two computers that are in the same subnet.

I do understand how the ip addresses are masked in each individual subnet, so how can I actually send to a specific ip in another subnet?

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

//some other codes

clientSocket.Connect("ip here", 9050); //target machine's ip address and the port number
clientSocket.Send(m_clientData);
clientSocket.Close();
```

edit: I have full information about the receiver, internal ip, external ip, mac address etc. So how can I send to this specific node?

Comment: What classes/method/protocols are you using right now? if sending the file via http to a http server running in the other computer, you can use the Webclient class's UploadData method

Comment: I added a snippet of my the implementation, I'm using sockets. I do have the gateway, mac address, local ip, etc of the other computer in another subnet, but I do not know how can I implement it.